# Custom event type not working in nodejs EventEmitter

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

my custom event type not working in nodejs EventEmitter. I have create a custom event type named "someMethod" but it's not working. It's not showing anything in console. Please view my code described below:

```
util = require('util');

var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

//Here is the MyClass constructor:

var MyClass = function() {
}

util.inherits(MyClass, EventEmitter);

MyClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {

  this.emit("customEvent", "arg1", "arg2");

};

var myInstance = new MyClass();

myInstance.on('customEvent', function(str1, str2) {

  console.log('got a custom event with the str1 %s and str2 %s!', str1, str2);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling `myInstance.someMethod()` so that the event can be emitted.

Comment: Thanks mscdex you save my time.